# How can we create users with the same email but not the same workflow?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-3.1

I want to make it possible to create several users, even with the same email address as long as they do not have the same "IdWorkflow" number.

But obviously it doesn't work... `result.Succeeded` is always false. & all I have is that message : "*User name 'test@test.com' is already taken.*"

What can I do...?

Register.cshtml.cs

```cs
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email, IdWorkflow = Input.IdWorkflow };
    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

        var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
        code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
        var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
            "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
            pageHandler: null,
            values: new { area = "Identity", userId = user.Id, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
            protocol: Request.Scheme);

        await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
            $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

        if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl });
        }
        else
        {
            await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
    }
    foreach (var error in result.Errors)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
    }
}
```

AspNetUsers.sql

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] (
    [Id]                   NVARCHAR (450)     NOT NULL,
    [UserName]             NVARCHAR (256)     NULL,
    [NormalizedUserName]   NVARCHAR (256)     NULL,
    [Email]                NVARCHAR (256)     NULL,
    [NormalizedEmail]      NVARCHAR (256)     NULL,
    [EmailConfirmed]       BIT                NOT NULL,
    [PasswordHash]         NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
    [SecurityStamp]        NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
    [ConcurrencyStamp]     NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
    [PhoneNumber]          NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
    [PhoneNumberConfirmed] BIT                NOT NULL,
    [TwoFactorEnabled]     BIT                NOT NULL,
    [LockoutEnd]           DATETIMEOFFSET (7) NULL,
    [LockoutEnabled]       BIT                NOT NULL,
    [AccessFailedCount]    INT                NOT NULL,
    [DateCreate]           DATETIME2 (7)      DEFAULT ('0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000') NOT NULL,
    [DateUpdate]           DATETIME2 (7)      DEFAULT ('0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000') NOT NULL,
    [IdWorkflow]           NVARCHAR (450)     NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);


GO
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UserNameIndex]
    ON [dbo].[AspNetUsers]([NormalizedUserName] ASC, [IdWorkflow] ASC) WHERE ([NormalizedUserName] IS NOT NULL);
```

Comment: Why don't you just make the IdWorkflow the PK of the table?

Comment: Because several users have the same IdWorkflow

Comment: Then how can you uniquely identify a user?

Comment: Well I want to make it with the Email + IdWorkflow

Comment: This table already has two constraints for uniqueness: the ID as a PK (must be unique) and then the declared constraint on the combination of NormalizedUserName (when not null) and IdWorkflow. Are you trying to insert a row where those two values already exist?

Comment: When using Asp.net core Identity, before creating a new user it will use the [UserValidator method](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/b7826741279450c58b230ece98bd04b4815beabf/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/UserValidator.cs) to check whether the name is duplicate or not, then if the entered name is existing, it will show the DuplicateUserName error. So, to prevent this issue, you must override the UserValidator method, you can refer [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50786399/) and the UserValidator data source to create the custom validator method.